# Can robots.txt redirect to a different domain?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, web-crawlers, robots.txt

I would like to know if I can put a 301 redirect on *robots.txt* file and have it hosted in a different location.   I'd like to have it on a cloud front layer.

example: `https://www.mydomain.example/robots.txt` redirects to `https://differentdomain.example/example/robots.txt`

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I assume you want to know if search engines will still honor robots.txt for your domain, even if it hosted elsewhere?

Answer (score 5):

Google allows the `robots.txt` 301 redirection you're talking about:

> Google follows at least five redirect hops as defined by RFC 1945 for HTTP/1.0 and then stops and treats it as a 404.
>
> https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt

I couldn't find any information about Bing's crawler.

It's my suspicion that smaller, poorly-written, non-search-engine bots might not be smart enough to follow the redirect, and might take the 301 status code as a blank check to hit your website.

If this is about keeping your `robots.txt` automatically up to date with the `robots.txt` on the other domain, I'd consider a reverse-proxy setup if possible.

On the other hand if this is about lessening the strain on your server by offloading your `robots.txt` to a CDN, well, your server is still going to have to serve all of those 301 status codes, which probably won't be much of a lighter load than just serving up the `robots.txt` file in the first place. And if serving your `robots.txt` file even tens of thousands of times per day is putting any real strain on your server, that's a surefire sign that there's an issue with your server.